# NPM shows "successfully" publishing to cache, but new versions of the package are not available

Tags: npm

NPM is reporting via email that a new version of a package of mine has "successfully" published. However, the new version does not appear in the GUI nor is it available to install. Oddly, I cannot publish over the same version, so clearly the package is somehow represented.

I feel like this is probably a service outage. But, I wanted to check if anyone else had encountered this behavior in a case which was not. I will note that there are a lot of versions of this package (77), and that I am on a free account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just experienced the very same issue when publishing a package. Received an e-mail that publishing was successful, but the new version of the package doesn't show up anywhere.

**Update:** Looks like the issue is solved now. The new version of my package now shows up in NPM.